# Coloured drop down menu not working in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

This is my code. I want to highlight the border of the dropdown in red if the checkbox is checked and if the value is 0. If the value is not zero and the checkbox's checked, green, if the checkbox is not selected, gray.

It gives me error but i cannot understand why.

In the js script i tried to insert another else, outside of the first if, but when i do that, the code doesn't work. If i do not insert that, the code works properly, but when i uncheck the checkbox, the colour red/green doesn't go away

```js
setInterval(() => {
          document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach((checkbox, index) => {
            const select = document.querySelector(`#punteggio${index+1}`);
            if (checkbox.checked) {
              if (select.value === '0') {
                select.style.borderColor = 'red';
                select.style.borderWidth = '2px';
              } 
            }
          });
        }, 100);
```

```css
[id^="punteggio"] {padding: 8px 10px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid gray; font-size: 16px;}
            section {margin: 30px 0; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between;}
            
            
            label, input {display:block; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 1.2em;}
            label {font-weight: bold; min-width: 150px; display: inline-block;}

            input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"]{padding: 10px;border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid lightgray; width: 100%;}
        
            button[type="button"] {width: 100%;padding: 10px; background-color: lightblue; border-radius: 5px; color: #000;cursor: pointer;margin-top: 20px;}
            
            #checkbox1 {width: 20px; height: 20px;border-radius: 15px; margin-right: 10px;}
```

```html
<ol id = "ordered">
          <li>
            <select id="punteggio1" >
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="Secondo esercizio" id = "checkbox1" style="display: inline-block;">Primo esercizio
          </li>
          <hr>
          <li>
            <select id="punteggio2">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="Secondo esercizio" id = "checkbox1" style="display: inline-block;">Secondo esercizio</input>
          </li>
          <hr>
          <li>
            <select id="punteggio3">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="Terzo esercizio" id = "checkbox1" style="display: inline-block;">Terzo Esercizio</input>
          </li>
          <hr>

        </ol>
```

Comment: if (checkbox.checked) you need to add else statement if checked red else gray

Comment: if (checkbox.checked) {
              if (select.value === '0') {
                select.style.borderColor = 'red';
                select.style.borderWidth = '2px';
              } 
            } else {
                  select.style.borderColor = 'grey';
                select.style.borderWidth = '2px';
            } add this it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
setInterval(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll('#ordered li').forEach((li) => {
        const select = li.querySelector('select')
        const checkbox = li.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')
        if(checkbox.checked) {
            if(select.value == '0') {
                select.style.borderColor = 'red';
            }
            else {
                select.style.borderColor = 'green';
            }
        }
        else {
            select.style.borderColor = 'grey';
        }   
    });
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
setInterval(() => {
          document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach((checkbox, index) => {
            const select = document.querySelector(`#punteggio${index+1}`);
            if (checkbox.checked) {
              if (select.value === '0') {
                select.style.borderColor = 'red';
                select.style.borderWidth = '2px';
              }else{
                select.style.borderColor = 'green';
                select.style.borderWidth = '2px';
              }
            } 
          });
        }, 100);
```

```css
[id^="punteggio"] {padding: 8px 10px; border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid gray; font-size: 16px;}
            section {margin: 30px 0; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between;}
            
            
            label, input {display:block; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 1.2em;}
            label {font-weight: bold; min-width: 150px; display: inline-block;}

            input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"]{padding: 10px;border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid lightgray; width: 100%;}
        
            button[type="button"] {width: 100%;padding: 10px; background-color: lightblue; border-radius: 5px; color: #000;cursor: pointer;margin-top: 20px;}
            
            #checkbox1 {width: 20px; height: 20px;border-radius: 15px; margin-right: 10px;}
```

```html
<ol id = "ordered">
          <li>
            <select id="punteggio1" >
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="Secondo esercizio" id = "checkbox1" style="display: inline-block;">Primo esercizio
          </li>
          <hr>
          <li>
            <select id="punteggio2">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="Secondo esercizio" id = "checkbox1" style="display: inline-block;">Secondo esercizio</input>
          </li>
          <hr>
          <li>
            <select id="punteggio3">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="Terzo esercizio" id = "checkbox1" style="display: inline-block;">Terzo Esercizio</input>
          </li>
          <hr>

        </ol>
```

Comment: The code to change color of the border needs to be moved out to a separate method and invoked whenever the checkbox is checked/unchecked and the value of the dropdown is changed.